# editing a trigger in mysql admin

Tags: mysql

Is there any syntax for editing a particular trigger in mysql php myadmin db. My db contains two triggers and they can be accessed using 'SHOW TRIGGERS' . But this command only giving me the triggers i want to read or edit that particular trigger, how can i do that?? i tried this

```
SHOW CREATE TRIGGER
```

but its not showing me the full info about the trigger it's just giving me the row which consists the value that it is created. but how to edit it pls tell me

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax for editing triggers in MySQL.  You need to drop it first and then re-create.  Additionally, you can also find some more information in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS table about a particular trigger.